# Why my incrementation not happening to the last element?

Tags: c++, pointers

This is my code trying to increment the elements by 1 using pointer. My last element is not getting incremented. Could you please tell me why

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void print_all( int *start,  int *stop)
 { 
  int *curr = start;
  while(curr != stop)
      {
    ++(*curr);
    ++curr;
    cout<< "\n"<<"content at address "<<curr<<" got incremented to "<< *curr<<"\n";    
      }
}


 int main()
  { 
   int a[] = {3,4,5};
   print_all(a, a+3);
   return 0;

  }
```

OUTPUT:

```
content at address 0x7ffe3ded3eb4 got incremented to 4

content at address 0x7ffe3ded3eb8 got incremented to 5

content at address 0x7ffe3ded3ebc got incremented to 0
```

Comment: Think about which values of `curr` you're actually printing.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's explain this with the first iteration of the loop:

1. Condition evaluates as `true`, body is executed.
2. Increment value at `*curr` by one.
3. Increment `curr` by one to point to the next array member.
4. Print **this next** array member; **the first member never gets printed!**

The `0` is an instance of undefined behavior; while just *pointing* one beyond an array is well-defined, *accessing* the value at that address is undefined.

The 3<sup>rd</sup> step is done too early. Exchange the 3<sup>rd</sup> with the 4<sup>th</sup> and you're fine.